# Region partitions (shapefiles) comparison in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, csv, dbf

I have 2 shapefiles, in each file the region is divided into zones.

Each zone from 1st ("large") file is "almost" a union of a few zones from 2nd ("small") file. Specifically, for each union in "small" file that union's boundary may not exactly match boundary of some zone in "large" file (there may be a small overlap).

If there's an overlap and some zone z_i from "small" file intersects with a few zones (Z_1,...,Z_n) from "large" file, I'd like to count z_i as a part of a zone Z_k for which intersection area of z_i and Z_k is the greatest (among all intersections of z_i and Z_1,...,Z_n).

Is there any simple way to make a .dbf (or csv) file with the following: for each zone Z_i from large file list a set of zones from small file which "correspond" to Z_i (their union is Z_i) ?

For example, if z_1 \cap z_2 = Z_1 and z_3 \cap z_4 \cap z_5 = Z_2 (\cap means intersection), then the resulting file dbf (csv) file looks like:

Small; Large

1; 1

2; 1

3; 2

4; 2

5; 2

Comment: I think your question would benefit from including a picture to try and describe what you are asking.

Comment: I find the use of the term Union a little confusing here. If I'm understanding right, it might be better to say each large zone is almost a *dissolve* of a few small zones. I gather you want a list of all small zones that make up each large zone, but you only want a small zone to count toward the large zone that it most lies within. Or perhaps you want to assign a large zone id to each small zone, but again only one id which it mostly lies within.